# If NodeJS caches required modules, why is my memory increasing the more I require a single module?

Tags: node.js, memory

I'm investigating a memory issue in a NodeJS application. In the application, we need to do some dynamic requires:

```
function executeSomeCode(module) {
    const m = require(module).run;
    run();
}
```

In the application, it can happen that the same module is passed to the `executeSomeCode` function multiple times. So it will be required multiple times.

My question is if this is expected to have an effect on memory usage and/or performance.

I created a little test:

```
function executeFoo() {
    const foo = require('./foo').foo;
    foo();
}

function main(){
    executeFoo();
    const first = process.memoryUsage();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        executeFoo();
    }
   
    console.log(first);
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}

main();
```

Where `foo` is just a simple module with a simple function logging a line. These are the numbers of a run:

```
{
  rss: 26824704,
  heapTotal: 5005312,
  heapUsed: 3157040,
  external: 1083723,
  arrayBuffers: 9898
}
{
  rss: 39321600,
  heapTotal: 8466432,
  heapUsed: 4497528,
  external: 1083763,
  arrayBuffers: 9898
}
```

As you can see the `rss` increases, but I'm not expert enough in NodeJS to be sure that this is a problem or if NodeJS will handle this. I read that NodeJS will cache the required modules, but then why is my memory increasing?

Comment: "So it will be required multiple times", wrong. It will be cached. The code is only loaded once. For every other "require" just your module `module.exports` is returned.

Comment: I guess what I mean is that my `require` statement will be executed multiple times.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean with "require statement will be executed multiple times", Yes it will, of course. But not your module code. `require` caches what you module exports (`module.exports`) and returns that every time you call `require` again. Your code that you try to `require` gets executed just once. The first time its loaded.

Comment: Exactly. I guess we're wording the same thing differently. The real question is, if NodeJS is caching the loaded modules, then why is my memory increasing?

Comment: Ohh, now i get it :D The question is, why are you worrying about it? Is this business critical? Dunno what node does under the hood that use memory. But dont forget that you for every loop allocate memory for init variables, function calls and all other kind of stuff. That must not exactly have to do with the require per se.

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to investigate a potential memory leak issue. So this is one potential path to investigate.